# Why is Media-Query not working with media-feature max-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have added max-width as a media-feature but no color changes when the width is less than 300px. I am checking it through Inspect element on my laptop. I have also turned its responsiveness and the size is 100%. please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Query</title>
    <style>
        @media screen and(max-width:300px){
            body{
                color:aqua;
                background-color:darksalmon;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni cupiditate, adipisci consequatur aliquam modi quo earum maxime ea impedit vitae obcaecati voluptatum. Adipisci repudiandae, officiis laborum itaque eum totam error.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam minus asperiores iste ratione aut autem laudantium aliquid, deleniti nostrum, delectus exercitationem, corrupti distinctio fugit commodi odio. Dolorem rem sunt temporibus!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in this line. space before (max-width:300px)
@media screen and (max-width:300px)

Comment: oh god ! Thank you very very much ! :)